# NSString Containing the Temperature for todays weather

Tags: nsstring, range, weather

I'm trying to detect if the temperature is in-between two sets of numbers. i.e. 70 - 79
If its in that range, perform an action, in my case set a specific image. I've tried using `rangeOfString:` but it was only looking for a number anywhere. I need it to look inside of a 10 digit area like 70 - 79.

Here is what I have for the temperature code

`NSString *temperature = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", weather.temperature];`

How would I take the string and search in-between 0-9, 10-19, 20-29...60-69, 70-79 etc etc etc?

If anyone can point me to an apple document or something I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you appear to have it in the form of a number, why not just use integer comparison?

```
if (weather.temperature >= 70 && weather.temperature < 80) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I knew it was something like that, guess i'm getting tired. Thanks Mate! Really appreciate it.